# how to fix my deployment configuration for showing some code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx

Im use the tutorial https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/ownserver/nginx/oss/trusty/deploy_app.html

for deploy my app to ubuntu remote server and try to deploy it, all succeded but for some reason the react isnt loading into the index.js - I also tried react create app for some clean react project ( still not working)

```
server {
        listen 9080;

        root /var/www/beautilit/code/public;

        index index.html index.htm
        server_name 10.1.18.11;
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Node.js app
    passenger_app_type nodejs;
    passenger_startup_file /var/www/beautilit/code/src/index.js;
}
```

it should show me the landing page of react create app but instead I get a clean white web page with the title setted "react app" so I believe the react just not loading into the html but why ?

it should be here : http://5.178.83.219:9080/
please help

Comment: you should check your request tab/console and see if there are any errors or failures in network calls. If you did not understand, you can post them here

Comment: you can check in the url , I have one error about the favicon